# Bind address already used C udp/tcp

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp, bind

I am trying to build a server, in this server first I have to receive a UDP and then keep waiting for more UDP messages and when I receive this first UDP message I need to create a TCP connection and wait for clients.

If I wait for the UDP message and I start with the TCP one, my server works perfectly, but I want to use fork, and with the father wait for more UDP messages and with the child start with the TCP part, but if I do this, I have a problem with the bind, because its already used by the UDP part... so.. is there a solution for this?

Is it possible to do what i want to?

I hope you to understand it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which `bind` do you have a problem with exactly? The child should inherit both the UDP and TCP listening sockets, and so it should not need to `bind` anything.

Comment: You are not having any problem with a TCP bind to a port because it is already used by a UDP socket. Please state your actual problem, and preferably show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Having open UDP and TCP sockets on the same port is fine. For example DNS works on UDP 53 and TCP 53 port. You should open sockets before fork, and then close in child what it doesn't need to use.

Answer (score 0):

UDP and TCP ports are in different spaces.  So you can have one socket bound to UDP/8888 and another bound to TCP/8888 with no problem.  If your child processes are trying to bind to the same TCP port, then you could have an issue.